# C# ASP.NET MVC Associative array in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this problem. I have holidays for this and and last year. You can use last year's holiday in this year. So lets say for example. I have 5 days left from 2013 and 20 days for 2014. I need something like in PHP.

```
$holiday = array();
$holiday['2013'] = 5;
$holiday['2014'] = 20;
```

So is there any better way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Something like following.

```
Dictionary<int, int> holiday = new Dictionary<int, int>();

holiday[2013] = 5;
holiday[2014] = 20;
```

Its better if you use `int` for year instead of string type like in your PHP code.

Comment: 'Better' is a bit subjective, we don't know exactly why he has got string literals in his example.

Comment: @MattC, better in a sense that `int` value could be used with DateTime constructor directly, instead of parsing. But yes you are right it depends on the OP's requirement.

Comment: yeah, not saying you're wrong. I agree with you but, as you said, in terms of the OP's question....

Comment: An int could use slightly less memory than the string, but it's not like that matters anymore.  We ain't developing on 256 byte Z-80 boxes anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Dictionary<string,int>`

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: why string, both key and value are of integer type.

Comment: Technically the OP has `Dictionary<string,int>`

Answer (score 1):

A similar - but strongly-typed - collection is a Dictionary. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).